# What are the Esperanto words for 'yaw' and 'pitch' of an aeroplane?

Tags: single-word-requests

La artikoloj en Vikipedio ne havas ligilojn al esperantaj resursoj. Mi petas sugestojn.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaw_(rotation)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the information is listed in easily accessible Esperanto-English dictionaries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mi povis trovi la vorton por *yaw*: [jori](http://vortaro.net/#jori).
La vorto por *roll* estas simple [ruliĝi](http://vortaro.net/#ruli%C4%9Di).
Mi ankoraŭ ne trovis la vorton por *pitch*. Tamen por simila movo por ŝipoj ekzistas la vorto [tangi](http://vortaro.net/#tangi).

Answer (score 2):

**Tangi** kaj **Jori**

Cetere, mi kredas ke estas neoficial regulo ke kiam oni petas tradukon de unuopaj vortoj oni unu kontrolu en vortaro, ekzemple, en la vortaro de Wells.

Comment: Mi jam respondis, donante tiujn vortojn. Do kial via komento de la vortaro supre ne jam sufiĉas?

Comment: Kiam mi komencis verki mian respondon, ne estis aliaj respondoj.